# Help window opening automatically

Tags: boot, 16.04, unity

I have recently installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS in my pc with 32 bit proccesssor and after I start my pc it keeps opening the help window automatically again and again. I had this same issue when I had windows 7 installed in the same PC and also few times in the boot menu while installing ubuntu.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a stuck key, or bad keyboard.  If it does it on two very different OSes, I'd remove keyboard & use another.

Comment: I'm using a external keyboard... but I'll try unplugging the Internal keyboard nd will let you know. Thank you.